# Use html css and bootstrap in Visual Studio 2022 with ASP.NET

Tags: html, css, asp.net, bootstrap-5, visual-studio-2022

How can I use html CSS and JavaScript design in Visual Studio 2022 where the ASP.NET controls allow the code to be performed?

I'm expecting that someone please solve my problem it's getting hard for me to start my work I'm creating a website as a project and I'm not able to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, and for at least 10+ years, the default in Visual Studio been to use jQuery, Bootstrap, and JavaScript.

So, it is not at all clear what you mean "how to use CSS and JavaScript"? You are free to even adopt AngularJS or quite much any modern based framework.

Furthermore, it is unlikely that you starting a Web Forms project today. However, Web Forms while old still has good support, and as I noted, for more then 10 years now the default templates and default setup in Visual Studio is to use Bootstrap themes and layout. That includes the default top navigation menu bar.

Let's drop in a button, and say an asp.net GridView.

When we click on the button, our code behind will load up the GridView with some data.

So, this markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdLoad" runat="server" Text="Show Hotels"        
    OnClick="cmdLoad_Click"        
    />
<br />
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  >
</asp:GridView>
```

So above is standard asp.net controls, but without any bootstrap classes.

Code behind to load up the data:

```
Protected Sub cmdLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim strSQL = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, City HotelName, Description
                  FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"

    GridView1.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

The above results in a rather poor looking page like this:

[image]

So, now, let's add the standard bootstrap classes to the above controls.

Hence:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdLoad" runat="server" Text="Show Hotels"        
    OnClick="cmdLoad_Click"        
    CssClass="btn"
    />
<br />
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    CssClass="table table-striped"
    >
</asp:GridView>
```

And now we have a full "responsive" grid and button:

[image]

And say you want to use the bootstrap info class for the button, then this:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdLoad" runat="server" Text="Show Hotels"        
    OnClick="cmdLoad_Click"        
    CssClass="btn btn-info"
    />
```

And now you see this:

[image]

So, even asp.net webforms can enjoy the Bootstrap classes, and I am hard pressed to think of any control that can't benefit from Bootstrap classes or themes.

So, nothing is stopping you from using Angular, React or any of the newer frameworks with asp.net pages.

And as above shows, most if not all of the controls are happy to accept the bootstrap classes.

And, as the above GridView example shows, adding a few of the basic bootstrap classes to the GridView results in a rather "amazing" transformation, and something that looked 20 years old now looks like any web site built with a modern new framework like bootstrap.

Note in above screen capture, the top application menu bar is a bootstrap one. So, even 10+ year old Web Form application templates use Bootstrap menu bars by default and out of the box.

So, I not aware of much if any limitations here in regards to you adopting Bootstrap classes for asp.net controls. You will find in most cases, that those standard Bootstrap classes work just fine against asp.net controls.

And the same advice applies to using CSS in asp.net web sites. Once again, you are 100% free to use quite much any CSS you want in such sites.